# App inventor runtime error about lists

Tags: runtime-error, app-inventor

app inventor 2 run-time error about lists.

*Select list item: Attempt to get item number 2 of a list of length 1: (Lingnan University Scholarship) Note: You will not see another error reported for 5 seconds.  How to get rid of this error*
What to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the error message is trying to tell you: you are selecting the second item of a list, which does only have one item.

Before selecting the second item, what about checking, if the list is long enough?

Answer (score 1):

As Taifun mentioned in your comments, if the user did not add all 4 items to the list, the `select item` will throw an error. There are multiple ways to solve it.

---

## Check When Clicked

[image]

This snippet checks if there are enough items to be display. If not, the customizable error message `ERROR: List is incomplete.` is shown.

## Check Individually

[image]

This snippet checks if there is an item for each label. The pro of this one is that the error message of each missing items can be customized, however it is longer compared to the previous solution.